# Finding matrix with lowest possible rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, matrix-completion

> Find the values of $x$ for which the matrix
>
> \begin{bmatrix}
>         x & 0 & 1 \\
>         0 & 1 & 0 \\
>         1 & 0 & x \\
>   \end{bmatrix}
>
> has the lowest rank.

Since the rank is the dimension of the row space of $A$, I should find $x$ for which the dimension of the row space is as low as it can possibly be. I performed Gaussian elimination on $A$ via the following steps:

\begin{bmatrix}
        x & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & x \\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & \frac{1}{x} \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & x \\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & \frac{1}{x} \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & x -\frac{1}{x}  \\
\end{bmatrix}

So I should now let $x - \frac{1}{x} = 0 $, more specifically let $x^2 = 1$ and thus $x = \pm 1$. Overall resulting in an overall lowest rank of $2$.

Is this the correct answer? And is it the correct way of thinking about questions such as these? Should I have considered the null space instead? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks right

Comment: For $x = 0$, clearly $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 3$. For $x \neq 0$, what you did is correct. Also, note that if $c_{i}(A)$ ($1 \leq i \leq 3$) denote the columns of $A$, then for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lbrace c_{2}(A), c_{3}(A) \rbrace$ are two linearly independent vectors. Therefore, $\operatorname{rank}(A) \geq 2$ for all $x$.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Note that you implicitly assume $x\neq 0$ as you write $\frac{1}{x}$. If $x=0$, the rank of the matrix is $3$ so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

For an alternative, slightly more intuitive solution: notice that no matter the value of $x$,

$$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}x\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} \right\} \text{ and } \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\x\end{bmatrix} \right\}$$

will both be linearly independent sets, and so the minimum rank is $2$. To have rank $2$,

$$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}x\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\x\end{bmatrix} \right\}$$ must be a linearly *dependent* set.

Two vectors are linearly independent if and only if one is a multiple of the other. This is clearly only the case here when $x=1$ or $x=-1$, so the matrix has minimal rank when $x = \pm 1$ as you concluded.

To answer your other questions: yes, this is a good way of going about this. Your method is in fact better than mine for the more general case. I just wanted to show you that in this case you can spot the answer without needing to do any row reduction. You *could* have considered the null space, but by the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) this is equivalent to what you’ve done, since you would just find that the null space has dimension $1$ implying that the rank is $3-1=2$.